# JQuery Cascade plugin to remember last selected state

Tags: javascript, jquery, cascade

I'm using the JQuery cascade plugin ([here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cascade))

I have it so I can select a book section in the first dropdown, which populates with chapters in the second drop down. e.g:

```
var list1 = [
            {'When':'0','Value':'0','Text':'Chapter 1'},
            {'When':'0','Value':'1','Text':'Chapter 2'},
            {'When':'0','Value':'2','Text':'Chapter 3'},
                            ...(snip..)

            {'When':'1','Value':'0','Text':'Appendix 1'},
            {'When':'1','Value':'1','Text':'Appendix 2'},
            {'When':'1','Value':'2','Text':'Appendix 3'},
                            ....(snip..)
];

function commonTemplate(item){
   return "<option value='" + item.Value + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>";
}; 
function commonTemplate2(item) {
            return "<option value='" + item.Value + "'>***" + item.Text + "***</option>"; 
        };
        
        function commonMatch(selectedValue) {
            return this.When == selectedValue; 
        };
```

Which is then called by:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {   
        jQuery("#section").cascade("#chapter",{                 
            list: list1,            
            template: commonTemplate,
            match: commonMatch          
        });
    });
```

my form is pre-populated with section0 and it's associated chapters. Everything works fine - when I select book 2, the script fires and populates the second drop down with the chapters from book 2 etc.

**My problem** is: When I select a book like "Section 2, Chapter 3", I would like that book and chapter to load while the form on the page displays "Section 2, Chapter 3". This way the user can quickly go to chapter 4 or whatever. Currently, when Section 2, Chapter 3 loads, the form defaults to "Section 1, Chapter 1" which is the default form value from the first time the user arrived at the page.

**My Question** is: How can I have a default value the first time, but when a user submits the form, the page reloads remembering the last selected section/chapter in the form?

Thanks.

Comment: I hope I asked the question properly - is there any information I left out?

Comment: do you have a running example? what server side language you use? how do you post the final chapter selection?